# Добрый день. У меня есть проблема с работай с файлами

Tags: python

Есть файл в котором есть определенный шаблон записи данных. Таких Данных там 1к+ строк. Нужно создать новый файл, в кортом будет краткая выжимка 1 файла и запись данных отличающихся от шаблона.
Шаблон текста вот такой:
C:\Users\lenovoPC\Desktop\files GNSS\obs\2014d_chast\0hdg2940.14d [1/100]:

- reading...done.
- processing...
  2014-10-21 23:59:45
  done.

Нужно ужать до:
0hdg2940.14d
2014-10-21 23:59:45
done.

Если встречаются ошибки как тут то надо так же ужать файл и записать предупреждение:
C:\Users\lenovoPC\Desktop\files GNSS\obs\2014d_chast\a12g2950.14d [50/100]:

- reading...[WARNING] Wrong interval value in the header of C:\Users\lenovoPC\Desktop\files GNSS\obs\2014d_chast\a12g2950.14d: None; using 30.0 instead.
  done.
- processing...
  2014-10-22 23:59:30
  done.

Что должно быть:
a12g2950.14d
[WARNING] Wrong interval value in the header of C:\Users\lenovoPC\Desktop\files GNSS\obs\2014d_chast\a12g2950.14d: None; using 30.0 instead.
2014-10-22 23:59:30
done.

Подскажите как лучше всего это реализовать и какие методы надо для этого использовать.